# RoR: creating and empty <select> dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `<select>` tag I am creating with the rails `select_tag` and I am populating its contents in JS. So i would like to initialize it to be empty, but when I write.

```
= select_tag "program", "<option></option>".html_safe, include_blank:true
```

I get the following error:

```
app/views/welcome/index.html.haml:53: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' ));}\n #{_hamlout.format_scri... ^
```

Here is my full form, which may be causing the error:

```
 =form_tag(controller: "school_applications", action: "calculate_price", method: "get", class: "calc_form") do 
    =select_tag "start_date", options_for_select(['February 9, 2015', 'April 6, 2015', 'May 4, 2015', 'June 1, 2015', 'June 29, 2015', 'July 27, 2015', 'August 25, 2015', 'September 21, 2015', 'October 19, 2015', 'November 16, 2015', 'December 14, 2015' ])
    -@option_array = (2..52).each.map {|i| ["#{i} weeks", i]}
    -@option_array = @option_array.unshift(["1 week", 1])
    = select_tag(:duration,options_for_select(@option_array))
    = select_tag(:fls_center,options_for_select( FlsCenter.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]})
    = select_tag "program", "<option></option>".html_safe, include_blank:true
    =submit_tag "Calculate Price"
```

Comment: ` = select_tag "housing_type", "<option></option>".html_safe, include_blank:true`

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct line / error message? (I find it hard to believe you'd get unexpected ';' on a line with no semicolons on it!)

Comment: @tpbowden i believe its a compiled semicolon, not one in the actual `.haml` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need one more `)` at the end of line 52

`=select_tag(:fls_center, options_for_select(FlsCenter.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}))`